# Cannot add android facebook connect project to svn in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, facebook, project

I am creating an android application which connects to facebook using the official facebook connect sdk via the methods given [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/). I am using eclipse on my iMac. I am successfully able to connect my app with facebook, post to wall etc, ie programming part is working smoothly.

To connect official SDK to an android project, we first have to create one project (say facebook project) for facebook connect and include src folders coming up with the facebook SDK. Then my actual android project reference this facebook project so that it can use SDK functions (see the link).

Now my problem is that I am using SVN to synchronize the project with my co-workers. When I commit my project It successfully get commited. But when my friends checkout they get compile error as they do not have the facebook project in their workspace. Is there any method to package this facebook project with my android project and upload it to svn via a single commit. There isn't any "add to project" kind of tick or switch when I reference the facebook project from my project. I hope my question is clear to you..

Comment: No encountered this problem before? How eclipse adds referenced android project into svn along with actual android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I've used for this is to create a stand-alone svn path for the facebook SDK, and then use svn:externals to import the facebook SDK into a subdirectory of the client project.

I'm using ant builds most of the time, so can't give you IDE instructions, however you should be OK if you use svn:externals to import facebook SDK into a subdir, then make that subdir a dependency.

I do this by setting the android.library.reference.n property (in default.properties) to point to the subdir

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello